# Can't launch android-studio in linux, getting this error Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main?

Tags: android-studio

I just downloaded android studio and I am trying to launch it by running studio.sh file, I am getting this error

> Error: Could not find or load main class com.intellij.idea.Main
>   I have looked it up on so and other sites and they all suggest to set the path correctly,

I have installed java and set up both Java_Home and PATH

> JAVA_HOME =/usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40
>   PATH= /usr/local/java/jdk1.7.0_40/bin(part of the total path variable)

here is the output of java-version

> java version "1.7.0_40"
>   Java(TM) SE Runtime Environment (build 1.7.0_40-b43)
>   Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM (build 24.0-b56, mixed mode)

Can anyone point out what I am doing wrong?

Comment: Try this, replace `/opt/android-studio` with the correct path: `sudo chmod g+r,o+r /opt/android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar`  And give me a ping with @A.B.

Comment: @A.B. my android-studio does not have bootstrap.jar and my android studio in at home/random_folder, does it have to be at /opt/android-studio?

Comment: No `bootstrap.jar`?! Which version is installed? And no, it doesn't have to be at `/opt/android-studio`

Comment: Correct the owner of the installation: `chown -R $USER:$USER ~/<your_android_studio_folder>/`. Don't forget the trailing `/`.

Comment: @A.B. Actually I just noticed that in /opt/intellij-idea-ce/  I have intellij installed, I can run it by running bin/idea.sh, I added that the /bin path in PATH also, but still android studio wont run. Any idea

Comment: [Intellij](https://www.jetbrains.com/idea/) isn't [Andoid Studio](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html).

Comment: Add the complete path of your `studio.sh` command.

Comment: @A.B. yeah on running android studio that is the error I am getting, that can't main itellij.idea.main

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/24357/discussion-between-a-b-and-dude).

Comment: If someone has this issue, try extracting the downloaded Zip again and make sure all the files are extracted correctly. If you are moving the directory, make sure it moves completely. In my case, the directory was moved before the file was uncompressed completely (dooh! +1 Homer point)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Either the file `<your_installation_path>/android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar` does not exist or has the wrong ownership.

Because the installation is located in your home directory, execute the following command that will give your user ownership:

```
sudo chown -R $USER:$USER <your_installation_path>/android-studio/
```

If that does not work, check if the file `android-studio/lib/bootstrap.jar` exists. If not, then download and extract the archive again.

Comment: `android-studio/lib/` directory doesn't exist for me. Should I create it and move `bootstrap.jar` into it ? If yes : what `.jar` should I download ( http://www.java2s.com/Code/Jar/b/Downloadbootstrapjar.htm ) ? I have Ubuntu 18.04 and these Java SDK : https://textuploader.com/d2vu3 .