# How to install Android Studio on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: software-installation, android, android-studio

I have downloaded Android-Studio and extracted it into documents. When I try to locate the `studio.sh` file located in `Documents/android-studio/bin`, I get an error.

How will I go ahead and install this Android Studio.

Comment: what's the error?

Comment: And maybe helpful: http://askubuntu.com/a/631039/367165

Comment: Comprehensive Guide: [Install and Configure Android Studio with Oracle JDK on Ubuntu 14.04, 14.10 and later](http://www.reversiblean.com/install-android-studio-oracle-jdk/)

Answer (score 1):

Another way to install Android Studio is through ubuntu-make.

Add the Ubuntu Make ppa:

```
 $ sudo add-apt-repository ppa:ubuntu-desktop/ubuntu-make
 $ sudo apt-get update
```

Install Ubuntu Make:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ubuntu-make
```

Install Android Studio:

```
$ umake android
```

For further information see [Ubuntu wiki](https://wiki.ubuntu.com/ubuntu-make).

Answer (score 0):

May be you have not made the script executable. So open a terminal and go to `Documents/android-studio/bin`:

```
cd `~/Documents/android-studio/bin
```

and make the `studio.sh` file executable by:

```
sudo chmod +x studio.sh
```

after pressing <kbd>Enter</kbd>, you will be prompt for root password, after entering password, hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>. Then type the below command and hit <kbd>Enter</kbd>

```
./studio.sh
```